# Can Anyone Tell me Why All Rects fires to same Activity

Tags: java, android

**MyImage class Extends View And Implements ontouchListener **
`enter code here`

public class MyImage extends View implements OnTouchListener {

```
Bitmap orignal;
Bitmap scaled;
Matrix m;
Context ctext;
ArrayList<Rect> rect;
```

**I have Four Rectangle and  all Rectangle are used to move to 
diff diff Activity**
        Rect rectangle0;
    Rect rectangle1;
    Rect rectangle2;
    Rect rectangle3;
    Rect rectangle4;
    private int X_POSITION;
    private int Y_POSITION;

```
public MyImage(Context context) {
    super(context);

    ctext = context;

}


@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

}

@Override
public View findFocus() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.findFocus();
}

@Override
public boolean isPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.isPressed();

}

@Override
public boolean isSelected() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.isSelected();

}



@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {


     X_POSITION = (int)event.getX();
     Y_POSITION = (int)event.getY();

    System.out.println(X_POSITION + "\t" +Y_POSITION);
```

**The Problem Occur here i dnt know why all rectangle fires to same activity and how can it be solved so that all rectangle fire to diff actvity**

```
    switch (event.getAction()) {

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:


        Intent i = new Intent(ctext , SelecterImage.class);
        ctext.startActivity(i);

    }
```

return true;

```
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    int X_WIDTH = canvas.getWidth();
    int Y_HEIGHT = canvas.getHeight() / 2;

    System.out.println(X_WIDTH + "\n" + Y_HEIGHT);

    Paint rectanglePaint = new Paint();
    rectanglePaint.setARGB(255, 0, 0, 0);
    rectanglePaint.setStrokeWidth(2);
    rectanglePaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);

    rectangle0 = new Rect(10, 420, 60, 380);
    rectangle1 = new Rect(70, 420, 120, 380);


    rectangle2 = new Rect(130, 420, 180, 380);
    rectangle3 = new Rect(190, 420, 240, 380);
    rectangle4 = new Rect(250, 420, 300, 380);


    canvas.drawRect(rectangle0, rectanglePaint);

    canvas.drawRect(rectangle1, rectanglePaint);

    canvas.drawRect(rectangle2, rectanglePaint);

    canvas.drawRect(rectangle3, rectanglePaint);

    canvas.drawRect(rectangle4, rectanglePaint);

    scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(orignal, X_WIDTH, Y_HEIGHT, false);

    canvas.drawBitmap(scaled, 0, 0, paint);

}


void setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    orignal = bitmap;

}



@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    return false;
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub




}   


}
```

**strong text**

Comment: I don't get it, you refer to a unique activity (SelecterImage.class), how do you expect to fire some others ? If you wanted to correct that, you should not apply the case on the MotionEvent.ACTION but on the getX() getY() and then compare those values with predefined areas, then launch the desired activity !

Comment: can u tell me how to use Rect to move to another activity

Comment: i use rectangle0.contains(X_POSITION , Y_POSITION).......but dsnt show anything

Comment: outside if() value of X and Y show but inside if it dsnt shows...

Comment: I truely don't understand what you're saying there. You recover X_POSITION and Y_POSITION on the onTouchEvent and then you just look for which rectangle DOES contain the position. What do you mean by your last comment ?

Comment: outside if() value of X_POSITION and Y_POSITION shows but inside if()it dsnt show values....

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that the onTouchEvent works correctly (does actually returns you X and Y like you do) and then

```
@Override 
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) { 


    X_POSITION = (int)event.getX(); 
    Y_POSITION = (int)event.getY(); 

    if (event.getAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
        if (rectangle0.contains(X_POSITION,Y_POSITION))
        {
           Intent i = new Intent(ctext , Activity1.class); 
           ctext.startActivity(i); 
        }
        else if (rectangle1.contains(X_POSITION,Y_POSITION))
        {
           Intent i = new Intent(ctext , Activity2.class); 
           ctext.startActivity(i); 
        }

        ....

    } 
}
```